Lagrangian for a free particle with parametrized time
There are two seemingly contradictory Lagrangians for a free particle with a parametrized time. The first is the one given by Dirac in his lectures on quantum mechanics. Take the action of a free particle [1][2] :
\begin{equation}
S[x] = \int_{t_i}^{t_f} \left(\frac{m}{2} \dot{\vec{x}}(t) \cdot \dot{\vec{x}}(t)\right) dt
\end{equation}
and introduce a new coordinate $t$, such that the new system $(t, x)$ depends on a parameter $\tau$.
We have by the chain rule
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt} = \dot{x}(\tau) \dot{t}^{-1}
\end{equation}
and with a change of variable,
\begin{eqnarray}
S[x] &=& \int_{\tau_i}^{\tau_f} \left(\frac{m}{2} \dot{\vec{x}}(\tau) \cdot \dot{\vec{x}}(\tau)\right) \dot{t}^{-1}d\tau.\\
\end{eqnarray}
This is apparently also the action used in Newton-Cartan gravity.
On the other hand, the method of coadjoint orbits gives the Lagrangian for a massive Galilean particle as
\begin{equation}
L = -\left(E_0 + \frac{1}{2} m \|\vec{v}\|^2 \right) \dot{t} + m \vec{v} \cdot \dot{\vec{x}}
\end{equation}
for a particle on a coadjoint orbit with energy $E_0$, mass $m$, and coordinates in the evolution space $(t, x, v)$. With some appropriate constraints, this turns out to give out that $E_0 = mv^2 / 2$ and $v = \dot{x}$, so that
\begin{equation}
L = -\left(\frac{3}{2} m \|\vec{v}\|^2 - \frac{m \|\vec{v}\|^2}{\dot{t}}\right) \dot{t} 
\end{equation}
Under the canonical time gauge $t = \tau$, all those actions are identical and give the standard Lagrangian (up to a sign but that doesn't change the dynamic), but I don't quite see if those two Lagrangians are meant to be the same in some sense.

Is the last equation (v3) from a reference? Which page?
